# How can I autosearch google maps from dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a cascading dropdownlist in an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm retrieving data from SQL Server to populate the dropdownlist in the controller. I would like to perform a search without having to manually press Enter, but rather by using a search button or automatically executing the search. Is this possible?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jROJy.png)

```
$(function () {
    $('#Drpilce').change(function () {
        var selectedSehir = $('#DrpSehir option:selected').text(); 
        // Get the selected value from the dropdown
        var selectedilce = $('#Drpilce option:selected').text();
         // Get the selected value from the dropdown

        $('#pac-input').val(selectedSehir.replace(/\s/g, "") + ',' +
        selectedilce.replace(/\s/g, "")); // Set the value of the search box input
        $('#pac-input').focus();   
    });

$('#DrpSehir').change(function () {

        var id = $('#DrpSehir').val();

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Home/ilcegetir',

            data: { p: id },

            type: "POST",

            dataType: "Json",

            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                var text = $('Drpilce').text();
                
                $('#Drpilce').empty();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    $('#Drpilce').append("<option value='" + data[i].Value + "'>" +
                    data[i].Text + "</Option>");      
                    console.log(text);

          } } });});});
```

```
      <div>

          @Html.Label("İller")
          @Html.DropDownList("DrpSehir", Model.Sehirler, "---Select City---", new { @class = 
          "form-control" })

          @Html.Label("İlceler")
          @Html.DropDownList("Drpilce", Model.İlceler, "---Select District---", new { @class = "form-
          control" })

          <button id="searchbutton" type="button">Ara</button>

      </div>
```

```
  <script>
      function initAutocomplete() {
          const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: { lat: 38.422995650397546, lng: 27.143915483670057 },
              zoom: 13,
              mapTypeId: "roadmap",

          });


          // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
          const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
          const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
          // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
          map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
              searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
          });

          let markers = [];

          // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
          // more details for that place.
          searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
              const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

              if (places.length == 0) {
                  return;
              }

              // Clear out the old markers.
              markers.forEach((marker) => {
                  marker.setMap(null);
              });
              markers = [];

              // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
              const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

              places.forEach((place) => {
                  if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
                      console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                      return;
                  }

                  const icon = {
                      url: place.icon,
                      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
                  };

                  // Create a marker for each place.
                  markers.push(
                      new google.maps.Marker({
                          map,
                          icon,
                          title: place.name,
                          position: place.geometry.location,
                      }),
                  );
                  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                      // Only geocodes have viewport.
                      bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                  } else {
                      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                  }
              });
              map.fitBounds(bounds);
          });
      }

      window.initAutocomplete = initAutocomplete;
  </script>
```

I tried form post method but not working.